# Sketch Text background

Tags: text, sketch-app, css

I need to add a background colour fill to my text.

I've tried the 'Generate text background' plugin, but its not working (says depreciated)

Any clues? (js fiddle of what i need http://jsfiddle.net/J7VBV/293/)

Answer (score 4):

I don't see the need for a plugin for that:

1. Create a text-layer (<kbd>T</kbd>) and set the width to `auto`.
2. Then add a rectangle (<kbd>R</kbd>), set a background color and give the rectangle the same `width` & `height` properties as your text-layer.
3. Then select both and align them to each other (horizontal & vertical centering) and send the rectange behind the text-layer.

Comment: This won't flow with the text. If you edit the text, you have to move the boxes around. If the text spans 2 lines, you have to have two boxes...

Answer (score 0):

Try use Sketch Dynamic Button. It's primarily for buttons, but it should work well for the thing you want to achieve. See more:  https://github.com/fuggfuggfugg/sketch-dynamic-button-3.5

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic Button plugin works, but from what I can see it has pretty much the same effect as:

1. adding text <kbd>T</kbd>
2. adding a rectangle <kbd>R</kbd>
3. and grouping them <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>/<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

You can then play with paragraph and resize settings to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no proper way to do this in Sketch. Your best shot is to create a box and put it underneath the text with the same dimensions as your text. If you want it to flow with your text, create a symbol out of it and set the layout to one of the first three in the dropdown depending on your text orientation.